# Maple - plotting error

Tags: graphing-functions, maple

I want to plot the following function in Maple 18.

```
p := (x, x0, w) -> exp(-(1/2)*(x-x0)^2/w^2)/sqrt(w*sqrt(pi))
```

and am attempting to plot it using the following command

```
plot(p(x, 20, 1), x = 0 .. 40)  #yes I am setting x0 = 20, and w = 1.
```

However I get the following error when attempting to plot

```
Error, (in plot) incorrect first argument exp(-(1/2)*(x-20)^2)/pi^(1/4)
```

I have read the documentation regarding this error, but it has not helped.  How would I plot my function "p"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maple, Pi, the well-known constant, is spelled **Pi**, not **pi**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still did not fix the error.

Comment: The code works for me if I just make the Pi correction. Perhaps you have assigned a value to x? That would cause a problem. Use a **restart** command before the other two commands.

Comment: I'm using maple 18, how about you?

Comment: I have Maple 16, 17, and 18. And I can tell you with certainty and many thousands of hours of Maple experience going all the way back to Maple 4 that there's nothing wrong with your commands other than the **pi**. If you've done a **restart** and corrected the **pi**, and it still doesn't work, then there must be something fundamentally wrong like a bad install.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I believe it is a bad install or something of that nature due to my code working on another computer.